# gitlab - "развернуть" коммит

Tags: gitlab

При большого объёма коммита в gitlab можно наблюдать "This diff is collapsed. Click to expand it.".

Как "развернуть" коммиты?

Comment: Click to expand it?

Comment: С предложением для клика не комфортно, от него нужно избавиться.

Comment: попробуйте написать в саппорт gitlab - это же платный продукт, вам точно и относительно быстро ответят на вопросы по его использованию

Comment: В заголовке коммита (там, где список файлов) есть кнопка «Expand All». Этого достаточно?